# Create columns in pandas based on text from another column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe in python with a column, named "Description" which contains a set of text element separated by "\n".
I would like to create new columns in the same Dataframe by splitting the text elements.
For instance, I have:

```
 Description

 '\nA: Elephant\nB: Cats\nC:Dog'
```

and I would like to obtain the corresponding number of columns with the associated element, something like this:

```
Description                         A         B    C

 '\nA: Elephant\nB: Cats\nC:Dog'    Elephant  Cat  Dog
```

How can I do in Python or Python Pandas?

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65824572/edit) your post as needed.

Answer (score 0):

First create list of dictionaries with `strip` and `split` and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Description':['\nA: Elephant\nB: Cats\nC:Dog',
                                  '\nA: Monkey\nB: Duck\nC:Dog']})
    
L = [dict([y.split(':') for y in x.strip().split('\n')]) for x in df['Description']]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index))
print (df)
                     Description          A      B    C
0  \nA: Elephant\nB: Cats\nC:Dog   Elephant   Cats  Dog
1    \nA: Monkey\nB: Duck\nC:Dog     Monkey   Duck  Dog
```

EDIT: If there is no `:` in splitted values, you can omit this values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Description':['\nA: Elephant\nB: Cats\nC:Dog',
                                  '\nA: Monkey\nB: Duck\nCDog']})
    
L = [dict([y.split(':') for y in x.strip().split('\n') if ':' in y]) 
           for x in df['Description']]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index))
print (df)
                     Description          A      B    C
0  \nA: Elephant\nB: Cats\nC:Dog   Elephant   Cats  Dog
1     \nA: Monkey\nB: Duck\nCDog     Monkey   Duck  NaN
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Applying your suggestion I'm receiving this error:
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: @user3043636 - Hmm, it means there is some data related problem? there is alsways `:` for separator?

Comment: you are right, sorry for that. Some rows in Description columns are empty.

Comment: @user3043636 - can you check edited answer? If still not working, can you cahnge data sample with problematic data?

Comment: no it still not working even if I have filled the empty row. I'm looking for problematic data.